# Como pular linha ao ler um txt em PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estou trabalhando em um sistema que vai rodar na Web, utilizando PHP e html e estou com uma dúvida.

Meu programa lê o txt e separa as informações através do delimitador ; grava em um array e salva as informações que eu quero dentro do banco de dados.

O que eu preciso é que o programa pule a primeira linha deste txt e faça a leitura a partir da segunda linha.

**O txt tem este formato:**

ID;CODIGO;NOME;PRODUTO;TIPO_MOV;COTAS;VALOR;NUM_NOTA;FORMA
1;;Teste;00.000.000/0001-00;A;0,00000000;80000;;TED

O que eu salvo é só as informações da segunda linha como posso fazer para pular a primeira linha?

**Meu código:**

```
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivoTxt']['tmp_name'];


$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode(';', $linha);
    var_dump($valor);

$id = $valor[0];
$Plataforma = $valor[2];
$Produto = $valor[3];
$Tipo_mov = $valor[4];
$Valor = $valor[6];
$Forma = $valor[8];
$Numero_banco = $valor[9];
$Numero_Agencia = $valor[10];
$Numero_conta = $valor[11];
$Digito_verif = $valor[12];
$Tipo_conta = $valor[13];
$cnpj = $valor[21];
```

Comment: pergunta básica.. o arquivo segue esse padrão sempre ? nunca muda ? se for isso vc pode começar pegando somente as linhas pares e ignorar as linhas impares ? sera q não é mais simples assim ?

Comment: Se `$dados` possui as linhas do arquivo, use `array_shift` para remover o primeiro elemento.

Comment: @ederwander creio não posso pegar somente as linhas pares, pois chega arquivo com mais linhas. O arquivo recebido é sempre neste padrão.

Comment: @Woss Certo, pesquisei sobre esse array_shift, vou tentar utiliza-lo. Se dados possui a linha ele retira a linha inteira não só o primeiro índice pela lógica. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolução:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("conexaoFin.php");

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivoTxt']['tmp_name']; // tmp_name é o caminho do arquivo

$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);
$TiraLnha = array_shift($dados);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);

    $valor = explode(';', $linha);

var_dump($valor);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Código abaixo explica:

```
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivoTxt']['tmp_name'];


$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);
$cabeçalho = dados[0]; // <- guardando cabeçalho
$dados = unset($dados[0]); // <- tirando ele dos dados
foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode(';', $linha);
    var_dump($valor);

$id = $valor[0];
$Plataforma = $valor[2];
$Produto = $valor[3];
$Tipo_mov = $valor[4];
$Valor = $valor[6];
$Forma = $valor[8];
$Numero_banco = $valor[9];
$Numero_Agencia = $valor[10];
$Numero_conta = $valor[11];
$Digito_verif = $valor[12];
$Tipo_conta = $valor[13];
$cnpj = $valor[21];
```